# Find the value of $\bigstar$: Puzzle 4 - In Between

Tags: mathematics, number-theory

This puzzle replaces all numbers with other symbols.

Your job, as the title suggests, is to find what number fits in the place of $\bigstar$.

All symbols abide to the following rules:

1. Each symbol represents integers and only integers. This means fractions and irrational numbers like $\sqrt2$ are not allowed. However, negative numbers and zero are allowed.
2. Each symbol represents a **unique** number. This means that for any two symbols $\alpha$ and $\beta$ which are in the same puzzle, $\alpha\neq\beta$.
3. The following equations are satisfied (this is the heart of the puzzle):
   $$
   \text{I. }\alpha\times\alpha+\beta=\gamma
   \\
   \space
   \\
   \text{II. }\delta\times\alpha+\beta=\varepsilon
   \\
   \space
   \\
   \text{III. }\gamma+\delta=\varepsilon
   \\
   \space
   \\
   \text{IV. }\beta^\alpha+\delta^\alpha=\beta^\delta+\alpha^\delta
   \\
   \space
   \\
   \text{V. }\zeta\times\zeta=\varepsilon
   \\
   \space
   \\
   \text{VI. }\zeta\times\alpha=\eta
   \\
   \space
   \\
   \text{VII. }\gamma<\bigstar<\alpha^\zeta
   $$

#### What is a Solution?

A solution is an integer value for $\bigstar$, such that, for the group of symbols in the puzzle $S_1$ there exists a one-to-one function $f:S_1\to\Bbb Z$ which, after replacing all provided symbols using this function, satisfies all given equations.

#### What is a Correct Answer?

An answer is considered correct if you can prove that a certain value for $\bigstar$ is a solution. This can be done easily by getting a function from every symbol in the puzzle to the correct integers (that is, find an example for $f:S_1\to\Bbb Z$).

An answer will be **accepted** if it is the first correct answer to also prove that the solution is the ***only*** solution. In other words, there is no other possible value for $\bigstar$.

Good luck!

Previous puzzles in the series:

[Puzzle 1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/59396/find-the-value-of-bigstar-puzzle-1) [Puzzle 2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/59405/find-the-value-of-bigstar-puzzle-2) [Puzzle 3](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/59413/find-the-value-of-bigstar-puzzle-3)

[Next Puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/59451/find-the-value-of-bigstar-puzzle-5)

Comment: __NOTE__: once an answer is accepted, the next one in the series will be posted shortly after. __Side Note__: to get $\bigstar$ use \bigstar in MathJax, and to get $\varepsilon$ use \varepsilon. This could come in handy when writing an answer to this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution:

> $\bigstar = 7$

Explanation:

> Plug III. into II.: $\delta×\alpha+\beta=\gamma+\delta$
>  Subtract I.: $(\delta-\alpha)×\alpha=\delta$
>  This works if $\alpha=2$ and $\delta=4$ (assumption A)
>  By IV. $β^\alpha+16=\beta^\delta+16 \implies β$ = -1, 0 or 1 – no other numbers have the same value for different exponents.
>  So by I. $\gamma$ = 3, 4 or 5.
>  And by III. $\varepsilon$ = 7, 8 or 9. Of these numbers, 9 is the only square, so
>  by V. $\zeta = 3$, $\varepsilon = 9 \implies \gamma = 5$ and $β = 1$.
>  Now VI. says $\eta = 6$
>  So in VII, $\gamma = 5$ and $\alpha^\zeta = 8$ and 6 is already taken, so 7 is the only solution for $\bigstar$.

Proof of assumption A:

> Because $\delta/\alpha=\delta-\alpha$ is an integer, $\alpha | \delta$. Let's say $\delta = n \times \alpha$, so the equation becomes $(n\alpha-\alpha)\times\alpha = n \times \alpha$; $\alpha$ cannot be 0 because it would imply $\beta=\gamma$, so $(n-1)\alpha = n \implies \alpha = \frac{n}{n-1}$. This is only an integer if $n=0$ (leading to $\alpha = 0$ which isn't possible) or $n=2$, which proves the assumption.

Comment: The upper bound in the last equation is $\alpha^{\zeta}$, not $\alpha^{\gamma}$, so there is a unique solution.

Comment: The mental typo strikes again ...

Comment: in your proof of ass. A, why does the equation $\alpha={n\over n-1}$ mean that $n$ is either 0 or 2?

Comment: @NODO55 e.g. 4/3, 11/10 or -2/-3 can never be an integer. That division only 'works' if $n-1$ is $\pm1$.

Comment: Again, why? Hint: try to get the equation of $\alpha$ to a form of $a+{b\over n-1}$ where $a,b$ are numbers, and see what you can derive from that.

Comment: I think my mathematics high school teacher would've approved the proof as it stands; anybody who recognizes the notation $\alpha|\delta$ will see immediately that $n-1$ never divides $n$ (except when $n−1$ is ±1).

Comment: Since I don't want this puzzle to focus on technicality, I will approve this. Just consider that "anybody.... knows that...." is something you want to avoid. This is why concrete proofs are needed. For example, to prove what you wanted, you can show that ${n\over n-1}=1+{1\over n-1}$, and the sole numbers that can divide 1 are 1 himself and -1 (and hence $n$ is either 2 or 0)

Answer (score 3):

Combining equations I, II, and III, we have

> $\delta \alpha - \alpha^2 = \epsilon - \gamma = \delta$, which means that $\alpha^2 - \delta \alpha - \delta = 0$.  This means that $\alpha = \frac{1}{2} \left( \delta \pm \sqrt{ \delta^2 - 4 \delta} \right)$.  The quantity in the square root must be a square number:  $\delta^2 - 4 \delta = m^2$ for some $m$.  But $\delta^2 - 4 \delta + 4 = (\delta - 2)^2$ is also a square number.  Thus, $m^2 + 4 = n^2$.  The only two square numbers that differ by 4 are 0 and 4, so $m^2 = \delta(\delta - 4) = 0$.  $\delta$ cannot be 0 by III, so $\delta = 4$ and $\alpha = 2$.

Applying these results to Eq. IV, we have

> $\beta^2 + 16 = \beta^4 + 16$, or $\beta^2 (\beta^2 - 1) = 0$.  Thus, $\beta = 0, 1$, or $-1$.  From Eq. II, we have $8 + \beta = \epsilon$, and from Eq. V we have $\epsilon$ is a square number.  Thus, $\beta = 1$, $\epsilon = 9$, $\zeta = 3$, $\gamma = 5$, and $\eta = 6$.

Thus, we can conclude that $\bigstar$ is

> 7, since we have $5 < \bigstar < 2^3 = 8$, and we know that $\bigstar \neq \eta = 6$.

Comment: "The only two square numbers that differ by 4 are 0 and 4". Why?

Comment: @NODO55: For any square number $n^2$, the next square number differs from it by $2n+1$.  This means that for $n > 2$, the difference between consecutive square numbers is greater than 4.  (And the difference between non-consecutive square numbers is even larger.)

Comment: Nice. Your proof is now complete