# Find the value of $\bigstar$: Puzzle 5 - Every little Symbol

Tags: mathematics, number-theory

This puzzle replaces all numbers (and operations) with other symbols.

Your job, as the title suggests, is to find what value fits in the place of $\bigstar$.

All symbols abide to the following rules:

1. - Each numerical symbol represents integers and only integers. This means fractions and irrational numbers like $\sqrt2$ are not allowed. However, negative numbers and zero are allowed.
   - Any symbol that is NOT numerical must be one of the following operations: $\{+,-,\times,\text{^}\}$. *Notice how all operation are binary operations. This means that all operation symbols must have a number on their left and on their right. Use that fact to your advantage!*
2. Each symbol represents a **unique** number/operation. This means that for any two symbols $\alpha$ and $\beta$ which are in the same puzzle, $\alpha\neq\beta$.
3. The following equations are satisfied (this is the heart of the puzzle):
   $$
   \text{I. }a\,@\,b=a\,@\,c
   \\
   \space
   \\
   \text{II. }a\,\#\,a=d
   \\
   \space
   \\
   \text{III. }d\,\#\,d=c
   \\
   \space
   \\
   \text{IV. }b=c\,\$\,d
   \\
   \space
   \\
   \text{V. }e\,\$\,e\,\%\,e\,\$\,b=c\,\%\,d\,@\,c
   \\
   \space
   \\
   \text{VI. }\bigstar=e\,\$\,d\,\%\,a
   $$

#### What is a Solution?

A solution is a value for $\bigstar$, such that, for the group of *numerical* symbols in the puzzle $S_1$ and for the *operational* symbols in the puzzle $S_2$ there exists a one-to-one function $f:S_1\to\Bbb Z$ and another one-to-one function $g:S_2\to\{+,-,\times,\text{^}\}$ which, after replacing all provided symbols using these functions, satisfies all given equations.

#### What is a Correct Answer?

An answer is considered correct if you can prove that a certain value for $\bigstar$ is a solution. This can be done easily by getting a function from every symbol in the puzzle to the correct values (that is, find an example for $f:S_1\to\Bbb Z$ and $g:S_2\to\{+,-,\times,\text{^}\}$).

An answer will be **accepted** if it is the first correct answer to also prove that the solution is the ***only*** solution. In other words, there is no other possible value for $\bigstar$.

Good luck!

Previous puzzles in the series:

[#1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/59396/find-the-value-of-bigstar-puzzle-1) [#2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/59405/find-the-value-of-bigstar-puzzle-2) [#3](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/59413/find-the-value-of-bigstar-puzzle-3) [#4](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/59421/find-the-value-of-bigstar-puzzle-4)

[Next Puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/59455/find-the-value-of-bigstar-puzzle-6)

Comment: __NOTE__: once an answer is accepted, the next one in the series will be posted shortly after. __Side Note__: to get $\bigstar$ use \bigstar in MathJax, and to get $\text^$ use \text^. This could come in handy when writing an answer to this.

Comment: Would it be possible for you give this series more descriptive titles? Perhaps use something that's different about this puzzle e.g. the missing operators.

Comment: Then what do you do when there isn't anything too special about the puzzle, or if the special part of the puzzle is practically a giveaway?

Comment: Side note to solution: apparently I completely missed a possible value for a... but surprisingly it worked out in the end, so good job solvers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\bigstar$ is:

> $11$

With

> $@ = \text^$
>  $\# = +$
>  $\$ = \times$
>  $\% = -$
>
>  $a = 1$
>  $b = 8$
>  $c = 4$
>  $d = 2$
>  $e = 6$

---

### **Explanation:**

$\text{I. }a\,@\,b=a\,@\,c$

> There are 2 ways this could be true with all distinct symbols:
>  **Possibility 1:**
>  $@$ is $\times$ operator, and $a$ is 0.
>  $@ = \times$
>  $a = 0$
>
>  **Possibility 2:**
>  $@$ is $\text^$ operator, and $a$ can be either $0$ or $\pm1$.
>  $@ = \text^$
>  $a = 1\space or\space 0\space or -1$

$\text{II. }a\,\#\,a=d$
$\text{III. }d\,\#\,d=c$

> From this operation, we can see that $a$ cannot be 0 since no matter the operation, there will be a duplicate between $a$, $c$, and $d$.
>  **As such, only possibility 2 is valid:**
>  $@ = \text^$
>  $a = 1\space or\space -1$
>
>  Building from that, $\#$ is not multiplication since $d$ and $c$ would be $\pm1$ too, and there would be at least a duplicate between $a$, $b$ and $c$.
>  $\#$ is not subtraction either, cause then $d$ would be 0, and $c$ would be equal to $d$.
>  **Therefore:**
>  $\# = +$
>  $a = 1\space or -1$
>  $d = 2\space or -2$
>  $c = 4\space or -4$

$\text{IV. }b=c\,\$\,d$

> if $\$$ is $-$, $b$ would be the same as $d$.
>  **Therefore:**
>  $\$ = \times$
>  $b = 8$
>
>  **By elimination:**
>  $\% = -$

$\text{V. }e\,\$\,e\,\%\,e\,\$\,b=c\,\%\,d\,@\,c$

> $e * e - e * b = c - d ^ c$
>  $e^{2} - 8e = (\pm4) - 2^{(\pm4)}$
>
>  **If $a$, $b$ and $c$ are negative:**
>  $e^{2} - 8e = -4 - (-2^{-4})$
>  $e^2 - 8e = -4 + 1/16$
>  No integer solution for e, so this is invalid.
>
>  **Thus $a$, $b$ and $c$ are positive:**
>  $e^{2} - 8e = 4 - 2^4$
>  $e(e-8) = -12$
>  $e = \{2, 6\}$
>
>  Since $d$ is already 2, $e$ cannot be 2 too.
>  **Therefore:**
>  $e = 6$

$\text{VI. }\bigstar=e\,\$\,d\,\%\,a$

> $6 * 2 - 1 = 11$
>  This should leave no other possibilities, since we've exhausted all possibilities for a-e and the symbols.

Comment: with Eq.1, why cant $@$ be $*$ ?

Comment: Ah, my bad. It is possible for @ to be * _if_ a = 0, but eq.2 quickly shows that if a = 0, d and c will be, too. Thus 0 is out of the question. I'll rework my explanation accordingly.

Comment: Another note: why cant $\#$ be $*$? a=-1 seems to work with Eq.2

Comment: Yep, just mentioned that case too in my edit. I think that made it easier to read/follow too, thank you for the tips!

Comment: You've got a slight problem left, if a=0 and # = ^, then 0^0=1, so you need to go one step further and say that in that case, you would have d = 1 and c = 1^1 = 1 which is a contradiction.

Comment: @Florian Bourse 0^0 cannot exist. consider the functions $x^0$ and $0^x$ when x is not 0: $x^0=1$ and $0^x=0$. Now when you take x=0, both functions are equal and therefore $1=(x=0)^0=0^0=0^{(x=0)}=0$, and as we know, $1\neq0$

Comment: 0^0 = 1 is widely used as a convention, just as 0*log(0) is often set equal to 0.
And it makes sense because x*log(x) tend to 0 when x tends to 0, so x^x tends to 1 when x tends to 0.

Comment: @FlorianBourse good catch. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

> $a=1, b=8, c=4, d=2, e=6, \bigstar=11$.

Because

> From $\text{I. }$, $@$ cannot be $+$  or $-$. If $@$ is $\times$, $a$ is $0$ and from $\text{II. }$, $d$ will also be $0$. so $@$ is $\text{^}$, so $a\text{^}(b-c)=1$ (we already know that $a$ is not $0$), so $a=\pm1$.
>
>  $\text{#}$ cannot be $-$, otherwise from $\text{III. }$, $c=0$, and from $\text{IV. }$, if $\$ $ is $\times$, $b=0$, if $\$$ is not $\times$, $b=d$, neither of these cases are acceptable.
>
>  if $\text{#}$ is $\times$, then from $\text{II. }$, $d=1$ and $a=-1$, and from $\text{I. }$, $b$ and $c$ are of same parity. So from $\text{IV. }$,$\$$ can neither be $+$ or $-$. there are nothing left to use for $\$$.
>
>  Hence $\text{#}$ must be $+$, and from $\text{II. }$, $d=2a$, from $\text{III. }$, $c=2d=4a$
>
>  From $\text{IV. }$, $\$$ cannot be $-$ otherwise $c=d$. So $\$$ is $\times$ and from $\text{IV. }$, $b=cd=8a^2$. Now $\%$ is minus.
>  Plug everything into $\text{V. }$
>
>  $e\times e-e\times b=c-d\text{^}c$
>  $e(e-8a^2)=4a-(2a)^{4a}$
>
>  We know from the very beginning that $a=\pm 1$, So LHS is clearly an integer, and if $a=-1$ the RHS will not be an integer.
>
>  Hence $a=1, b=8, c=4, d=2$, plug them to the RHS of $\text{V. }$ to get $-12$. Solve a quadratic equation the get $e=2$ or $e=6$. $d=2$, so $e=6$.
>
>  Now plug everything to the final formula to get $\bigstar=6\times2-1=11$

Comment: Still struggling with type setting. Not sure what I have done wrong but can you take a look? @NODO55

Comment: You need to add 2 spaces at the end of the sentence for it to register as a newline.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out! You saved my afternoon. @Votbear

Comment: Seems fine to me.