# Find the value of $\bigstar$: Puzzle 6 - Enclosed Operations

Tags: mathematics, number-theory

This puzzle replaces all numbers (and operations) with other symbols.

Your job, as the title suggests, is to find what value fits in the place of $\bigstar$.

All symbols abide to the following rules:

1. - Each numerical symbol represents integers and only integers. This means fractions and irrational numbers like $\sqrt2$ are not allowed. However, negative numbers and zero are allowed.
   - Any symbol that is NOT numerical must be one of the following operations: $\{+,-,\times,\text{^}\}$. *Notice how all operation are binary operations. This means that all operation symbols must have a number on their left and on their right. Use that fact to your advantage!*
2. Each symbol represents a **unique** number/operation. This means that for any two symbols $\alpha$ and $\beta$ which are in the same puzzle, $\alpha\neq\beta$.
3. The following equations are satisfied (this is the heart of the puzzle):
   $$
   \text{I. }a\,@\,a=b\,@\,b
   \\
   \space
   \\
   \text{II. }a\,\#\,a=a\,\$\,a
   \\
   \space
   \\
   \text{III. }b\,\%\,b=a
   \\
   \space
   \\
   \text{IV. }c=a\,\#\,a\,\#\,a\,@\,a\,\#\,a\,@\,b
   \\
   \space
   \\
   \text{V. }d\,\$\,(e\,@\,b)=(c\,@\,e)\,\$\,(e\,\#\,a)
   \\
   \space
   \\
   \text{VI. }d=e\,\#\,a\,\%\,f\,\#\,a
   \\
   \space
   \\
   \text{VII. }d=g\,\$\,a
   \\
   \space
   \\
   \text{IIX. }e\,\$\,(e\,\%\,f)\,@\,a\,\%\,c=\bigstar
   $$

#### What is a Solution?

A solution is a value for $\bigstar$, such that, for the group of *numerical* symbols in the puzzle $S_1$ and for the *operational* symbols in the puzzle $S_2$ there exists a one-to-one function $f:S_1\to\Bbb Z$ and another one-to-one function $g:S_2\to\{+,-,\times,\text{^}\}$ which, after replacing all provided symbols using these functions, satisfies all given equations.

#### What is a Correct Answer?

An answer is considered correct if you can prove that a certain value for $\bigstar$ is a solution. This can be done easily by getting a function from every symbol in the puzzle to the correct values (that is, find an example for $f:S_1\to\Bbb Z$ and $g:S_2\to\{+,-,\times,\text{^}\}$).

An answer will be **accepted** if it is the first correct answer to also prove that the solution is the ***only*** solution. In other words, there is no other possible value for $\bigstar$.

Good luck!

Previous puzzles in the series:

[#1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/59396/find-the-value-of-bigstar-puzzle-1) [#2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/59405/find-the-value-of-bigstar-puzzle-2) [#3](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/59413/find-the-value-of-bigstar-puzzle-3) [#4](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/59421/find-the-value-of-bigstar-puzzle-4) [#5](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/59451/find-the-value-of-bigstar-puzzle-5)

[Next Puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/59487/find-the-value-of-bigstar-puzzle-7-boss-battle)

Comment: __NOTE__: once an answer is accepted, the next one in the series will be posted shortly after. __Side Note__: to get $\bigstar$ use \bigstar in MathJax, and to get $\text^$ use \text^. This could come in handy when writing an answer to this.

Comment: is a^a^a = a^(a^a) or (a^a)^a ?

Comment: Usually a^a^a is considered a^(a^a) as (a^a)^a can be simplified to a^(2a)

Comment: @NODO55 (a^a)^a = a^(a^2). But you are right that a^a^a = a^(a^a)

Comment: @Kurga right, messed that bit up.

Comment: I actually find a solution different from the intended one. I hope you can prove me wrong.

Comment: I must say I am amazed. This also means that I had a flaw in my proof (and I checked, I made a false assumption that ${2e\over e-1}$ must be an integer) I now added an Equation between VI and VII that eliminates the unexpected solution... But seriously, good job @Weijun Zhou ! (also sorry for brute force removing the alternate solution, but singularity beats all)

Comment: You labbeled the now 8th equation with the roman 9

Comment: Roman 8 is not written this way.

Comment: technically it can be written either as VIII (4 letters, 5 + 1*3) or as IIX (3 letters, 10 - 2*1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is (were ?)

> $a=2, b=1, c=11, d=36, e=6, f=0, g=18, \bigstar=45$.
>  $@$ is $-$, $\%$ is $+$, $\#$ is $\text^$, and $\$$ is $\times$.

and (before equation $\text{VII. }$ is inserted)

> $a=2, b=1, c=3, d=32, e=-5, f=21, \bigstar=152587890626$.
>  $@$ is $-$, $\%$ is $+$, $\#$ is $\times$, and $\$$ is $\text^$.

The newly inserted $\text{VII. }$ invalidates the latter solution because

> $32=d=g^2$, and $g$ is not an integer.

My reasoning is that

> From $\text{I. }$, $@$ cannot be $+$ since $a\neq b$, $@$ cannot be $\text^$ because of the following,
>
>  First it should be noted that $0^0$ is undefined, if we consider $f(n)=\left|n^n\right| (n\in \mathbb Z)$ , then for $n<-1$, $f(n)$ is strictly increasing with $n$ but strictly smaller than $1$, and for $n>1$ ,$f(n)$ is strictly increasing with $n$ and strictly larger than $1$, and of course, $1^1\neq (-1)^{-1}$ and $f(1)=f(-1)=1$.
>
>  So $@$ can only be $-$ or $\times$. For the latter case, $a=-b$.
>
>  For $\text{II. }$, the possible values that the LHS and RHS can take form the set $\{2a, 0, a^2, a^a\}$, and two of them are equal, enumerating all possibilities result in $a=0$ ,$a=1$, or $a=2$.
>
>  From $\text{III. }$, $b\%b=a$, if $a=2$ and $b=-a=-2$, there is no choice for $\%$ to make this equation true.
>  If $a=1$ and $b=-a=-1$, then $\%$ must be $\times$ and $@$ cannot be $\times$.
>  If $a=0$ and $b=-a=0$ then $a=b$ and it is not allowed.
>  One way or another, $@$ cannot be $\times$ so $@$ is $-$.
>
>  Now if $a=1$, then $\{\#,\$\}=\{\times,\text^\}$, so $\%$ is $+$, but $b\%b=a$ means $2b=1$ and $b$ is not an integer,
>  if $a=0$, then $b\%b=a$ either means $\%$ is $-$(which is already taken by $@$), or $b=0=a$, neither of them are allowed.
>  Hence $a=2$.
>
>  Now $b\%b=2$, $\%$ cannot be $\text^$ or $\times$, the only choice is $+$, and $b=1$.
>
>  $\text{IV. } $ now becomes $c=2\#2\#2-2\#2-1$. If $\#$ is $\times$, then $c=3$, if $\#$ is $\text^$, then $c=11$.

Now we have 2 choices, each leading to a valid solution to the original puzzle.

The first one, which is invalidated by the newly added $\text{VII. }$, is

> $\textbf{A.}$ $c=3$, $\#$ is $\times$, $\$$ is $\text^$
>  $\text{V. }$ now becomes,
>  $$d\text^(e-1)=(3-e)\text^(e\times2)$$
>  $$d^{e-1}=(3-e)^{2e}$$
>
>  $\text{VI. }$ becomes,
>  $$d=e\times2+f\times2$$
>  $$d=2e+2f$$
>  
>  Combine them to make,
>  $$(2e+2f)^{e-1}=(3-e)^{2e}$$
>
>  $$(2e+2f)^{e-1}=(e^2-6e+9)\times(e^2-6e+9)^{e-1}$$
>  
>  $(e^2-6e+9)$ is clearly an integer, and it is the $e-1$ power of a rational number(call it $k$), which must also be an integer or its reciprocal. Let $l=k$ if $k$ is an integer, and $l=\frac1k$ if $k$ is the reciprocal of an integer.
>
>  $$\left|e-3\right|^2=(e-3)^2=l^{\left|e-1\right|}\ge l^{\left|e-3\right|-2}$$
>
>  Consider $g(n)=\frac{\left|l\right|^{n-2}}{n^2} (n\in\mathbb Z^+)$. For $\left|l\right|>1$, $g(n)$ increases monotonically and is strictly larger than 1 when $n>8$, which contradicts the inequality above. So we are left with only a few cases to consider.
>
>  if $\left|l\right|=0$, then $e=3=c$ and is ruled out.
>  If $\left|l\right|=1$, then $e=4$, $l=1$, but $l=1$ means $e^2-6e+9=2e+2f$, and this can be ruled out by parity.
>
>  Now the only thing left unchecked is $\left|e-3\right|<9$, now come back to
>  $$(e-3)^2=l^{\left|e-1\right|}$$
>   Enumerating $e$ to find out that $e\in\{-5, -1, 0, 2, 3, 4\}$, otherwise $l$ is not an integer.
>  In the set above, $2$ and $3$ are already used.
>  if $e=0$, then $l=9$, $9(2e+2f)=e^2-6e+9$. This can be ruled out by parity.
>  if $e=-1$, then $l=\pm4$, $\pm4(2e+2f)=e^2-6e+9$, $f=3=c$ or $f=-1=e$, neither is acceptable.
>  if $e=4$, then $l=1$, $2e+2f=e^2-6e+9$. This can be ruled out by parity.
>  if $e=-5$, then $l=\pm2$, $\pm2(2e+2f)=e^2-6e+9$, $f=21$ or $f=-11$, and $d=32$ or $d=-32$, respectively.
>
>  Now plug in everything to $\text{VIII. }$, if $f=-11$, $\bigstar$ is not an integer. If $f=21$, we have a solution, which was valid before the equation $\text{VII. }$ was inserted (there was no variable $g$ in the original puzzle).
>  $$(-5)\text^(-5+21)-2+3=152587890626$$.

The other choice is

> $\mathbf{B. } $ $c=11$ and $\#$ is $\text^$ and $\$$ is $\times$,
>   $\text{V. }$ now becomes,
>  $$d\times(e-1)=(11-e)\times(e\text^2)$$
>  $$d(e-1)=(11-e)e^2$$
>
>  $\text{VI. }$ becomes,
>  $$d=e\text^2+f\text^2$$
>  $$d=e^2+f^2$$
>  
>   Combine them to make 
>  $$(e^2+f^2)(e-1)=(11-e)e^2$$
>  $$f^2(e-1)=(12-2e)e^2$$
>
>  Now $f^2$ is nonnegative and $e^2$ is also nonnegative ,so $e<7$ and $e>0$.
>  
>  For every $e$ calculate the corresponding $f$. $1,2,3$ are already used, if $e=4$ or $e=5$, $(12-2e)e^2$ is not a multiple of $e-1$. For $e=6$ we have the solution $f=0$.
>
>  Finally, plug in everything to $\text{VIII. }$ to get
>  $$6\times(6+0)-2+11=45$$
>
>  From the newly added $\text{VII. }$, the value of the newly added variable $g$ is,
>  $$d=g\times2, g=18.$$

Comment: well done. A proof much more complex than my version however. You are the first person to outright prove the singularity of the solution other than myself.

Comment: Thank you. Finally a case that I am not beaten by fellow answerers by speed... I am happy, no, eager, to learn the much simpler version.

Answer (score 1):

my suggestion is

> 45

based on

> a=2
>  b=1
>  c=11
>  d=36
>  e=6
>  f=0
>
>  and
>
>  @ -> -
>  # -> ^
>  $ -> x
>  % -> +

as we then have

> I.2-2 = 1-1
>  II. 2^2 = 2x2
>  III. 1+1 = 2
>  IV. 11 = 2^2^2 - 2^2 - 1
>  V. 36 x (6-1) = (11-6)x(6^2)
>  VI. 36 = 6^2 + 0^2
>  VII. 6x(6+0) - 2 + 11 = 45

Comment: Please wrap your answers / partial answers in [`>! ` Spoilers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/editing-help#spoilers)

Comment: That looks right. Now try to prove that value for $\bigstar$ is the only possible value.

Answer (score 0):

## Partial answer:

From $\text{I. }a\,@\,a=b\,@\,b$ we can see that

> $@$ is neither $+$ or $*$, because that would imply $a=b$, so $@\in\{-, \text^\}$
>
>  If $@=-$, then $a\in\Bbb Z$ and $b\in\Bbb Z$ with $a\neq b$
>  If $@=\text^$, then $a\in\{0,1\}$ and $b\in\{0,1\}$ with $a\neq b$ (here I assume $0^0=1=1^1$, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_to_the_power_of_zero))

From $\text{II. }a\,\#\,a=a\,\$\,a$ we can either deduce

> $a=2$, if $\#\in\{+,*,\text^\}$ and $\$\in\{+,*,\text^\}$, because $2+2=2*2=2^2$  or
>  $a=0$, if either
>  $\#=-$ and $\$\in\{+,*\}$ or
>  $\$=-$ and $\#\in\{+,*\}$ because
>  $a^a=0^0=1\neq 0 = a$

So

> $a=0\lor a=2$

In $\text{III. }b\,\%\,b=a$ we can see that

> $\%\notin \{*,\text^\}$
>  because neither $b*b$ nor $b^b$ have solutions in $\Bbb Z$ so that $b\,\%\, b = a$ with $a\in\{0,2\}$ and $a\neq b$
>  $\Rightarrow\,\%\in \{+,-\}$
>
>  If $\%=\,-$, then $b\,-\,b\,=\,a\,=\,0$, but $a=0$ only if either $\#=-$ or $\$=-$
>  $\Rightarrow\%\,=\,+$

Combining $\text{I. }$ and $\text{III. }$

> $b\,+\,b\,=\,2b=\,a$ with $a\neq b \neq 0$
>  $\Rightarrow 2a\,@\,2a\,=\,a\,@\,a$
>  we get $@\neq \text^$, because the equation will only hold if $a=0$
>  $\Rightarrow @\,=\,-$
>  $\Rightarrow\,a\,=\,2$
>  $\Rightarrow\,b\,=\,1$
>  $\Rightarrow\#\in\{*,\text^\}$ and $\$\in\{*,\text^\}$

Now looking at $\text{IV. }c=a\,\#\,a\,\#\,a\,@\,a\,\#\,a\,@\,b$

> With $\#\,=\,\text^$
>  $\Rightarrow \$\,=\,*$
>  $c=2\,\text^\,2\,\text^\,2\,-\,2\,\text^\,2\,-\,1\,=16-4-1=11$

Plugging into $\text{V. }d\,\$\,(e\,@\,b)=(c\,@\,e)\,\$\,(e\,\#\,a)$ gives

> $d\,*(e\,-\,1)\,=\,(11\,-\,e)\,*e^2$
>  $d=\frac{11e^2\,-\,e^3}{e\,-\,1}$
>  Which gives integer solutions $(d\,,\,e)$:
>  - $(-162, -9)$
>  - $(-48, -4)$
>  - $(-6, -1)$
>  - $(0, 0)$  This we can ignore because $d\neq e$
>  - $(0, 11)$

Plug into $\text{VI. }d=e\,\#\,a\,\%\,f\,\#\,a$

> $d\,=e^2+f^2$
>  We can see that $d\ge 0$, so the only pair $(d\,,\,e)$ that would fit is $(0, 11)$
>  In our case this can't be used because
>  $0\,=\,11^2\,+\,f^2\rightarrow f\,=\pm\sqrt{-121}\notin\Bbb Z$
>  All solution pairs from equation $\text{V. }d\,\$\,(e\,@\,b)=(c\,@\,e)\,\$\,(e\,\#\,a)$ has been ruled out
>  $\Rightarrow \#\neq \text^$
>  $\Rightarrow \#\,=\,*\land\$\,=\text^$
>  $\Rightarrow c=2\,*\,2\,*\,2\,-\,2\,*\,2\,-\,1\,=8-4-1=3$

Updating the remaining equations

> $\text{V. }d\,^{e\,-\,1}=(3\,-\,e)\,^{2e}$
>  $\text{VI. }d=e\,*\,2\,+\,f\,*\,2=2\,(\,e\,+\,f\,)$
>  $\text{VII. }e\,^{e\,+\,f}\,-\,2\,+\,3=e\,^{e\,+\,f}\,+1=\bigstar$

*To be continued...*

Comment: for your conclusions on statement II, why only 2 or 0 work, and why with that sort of operation assignment? For example, for a=0, $\#=+$, $\$=*$ might work...
Providing explanation to your conclusions is important since you might miss more things.