# Find the value of $\bigstar$: Puzzle 7 - Boss Battle

Tags: mathematics, number-theory

This puzzle replaces all numbers with other symbols.

Your job, as the title suggests, is to find what value fits in the place of $\bigstar$. To get the basic idea down, I recommend you solve [Puzzle 1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/59396/find-the-value-of-bigstar-puzzle-1) first.

All symbols abide to the following rules:

1. Each numerical symbol represents integers and only integers. This means fractions and irrational numbers like $\sqrt2$ are not allowed. However, negative numbers and zero are allowed.
2. Each symbol represents a **unique** number. This means that for any two symbols $\alpha$ and $\beta$ which are in the same puzzle, $\alpha\neq\beta$.
3. The following equations are satisfied (this is the heart of the puzzle):
   $$
   \text{I. }a\times a=a
   \\
   \space
   \\
   \text{II. }b=a+a+a+a
   \\
   \space
   \\
   \text{III. }b^c+d^c=e^c
   \\
   \space
   \\
   \text{IV. }b-d=c\times d+f
   \\
   \space
   \\
   \text{V. }f=(e+a+a)\times g
   \\
   \space
   \\
   \text{VI. }b\times c=\bigstar+g
   \\
   \space
   \\
   \text{VII. }b\times\bigstar+c=a+f
   $$

#### What is a Solution?

A solution is a value for $\bigstar$, such that, for the group of symbols in the puzzle $S_1$ there exists a one-to-one function $f:S_1\to\Bbb Z$ which, after replacing all provided symbols using these functions, satisfies all given equations.

#### What is a Correct Answer?

An answer is considered correct if you can prove that a certain value for $\bigstar$ is a solution. This can be done easily by getting a function from every symbol in the puzzle to the correct values (that is, find an example for $f:S_1\to\Bbb Z$).

An answer will be **accepted** if it is the first correct answer to also prove that the solution is the ***only*** solution. In other words, there is no other possible value for $\bigstar$.

Good luck!

Previous puzzles in the series:

[#1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/59396/find-the-value-of-bigstar-puzzle-1) [#2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/59405/find-the-value-of-bigstar-puzzle-2) [#3](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/59413/find-the-value-of-bigstar-puzzle-3) [#4](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/59421/find-the-value-of-bigstar-puzzle-4) [#5](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/59451/find-the-value-of-bigstar-puzzle-5) [#6](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/59455/find-the-value-of-bigstar-puzzle-6)

[Next Puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/59606/find-the-value-of-bigstar-puzzle-8-inequality)

Comment: __NOTE__: This is the last puzzle in this series (that is already made). If you enjoyed this, tell me so that I know working on another 7 puzzles would be worth it. __Side Note__: to get $\bigstar$ use \bigstar in MathJax. This could come in handy when writing an answer to this. __BONUS__: Since this is the last puzzle in the series, which has never been solved by anyone other than me, the first person to _solve_ this puzzle may grant himself the title of **Mercury**.

Comment: I have discovered a marvelous proof of the solutions for Eq. III, which this comment box is too small to contain.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert when writing an answer, make sure to use proper _Fermatting_, it helps out with seeing the solution more clearly.

Comment: To clarify: does your condition 2 mean that all the $a,b,c,d,e,f,g,\bigstar$ here must be distinct, or only that any two *which appear in the same equation* must be distinct?

Comment: if they appear in the same _puzzle_ (and yes, they do) they must be distinct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the solution is

> $\bigstar = 6$.

Proof:

> The first equation implies that $a^2 - a = a (a - 1) = 0$, which implies that $a = 1$ or $a = 0$.  Since $4a = b$ and $a \neq b$, this means that $a = 1$ and $b = 4$.

Examining Eq. IV, we note that

> We cannot have $c = -1$ or $d = 0$, as in either case we have $b = f$.

This fact will help us in examining Eq. III:

> Eq. III is Fermat's Last Theorem in disguise.  If $c = 0$, there is no solution.  **Assume temporarily that $e$ is non-zero.**  If either $d$ or $e$ are negative, the overall equation is equivalent to an equation of the form $b^c \pm |d|^c = \pm |e|^c$, which can be rearranged into the form $x^c + y^c = z^c$ for $\{x, y, z\}$ being some permutation of $\{b, |d|, |e|\}$–i.e., all positive integers.  If $c > 0$, this will be the standard version of Fermat's Last Theorem, and so we know that $c \leq 2$.  If $c < 0$, then we can rewrite this equation as $(yz)^{-c} + (xz)^{-c} = (xy)^{-c}$, and by the same logic, there cannot be a solution if $-c > 2$.  We have already ruled out $c = +1 = a$, and $c = -1$ (in the block above).  Thus, we have $c = -2$ or $c = +2$.

Taking these two cases in turn:

> If $c = +2$, then $(b, \pm d, \pm e)$ form a Pythagorean triple.  (Note that we already established $d \neq 0$.)  The only Pythagorean triple containing $b = 4$ is $(4, 3, 5)$.  (This can be proven by using [standard results concerning the generation of Pythagorean triples.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#Generating_a_triple))  Thus, $d = \pm 3$ and $e = \pm 5$.  If $d = +3$, then Eq. IV implies that $f = -5$, and Eq. V implies that either $-5 = 7g$ or $-5 = (-3)g$, which means $g$ is not an integer.  If $d = -3$, then Eq. IV implies that $f = 1 = a$, which is not allowed.

For the other case,

> When $c = -2$, we cannot have $d = 0$ or $e = 0$.  Under this assumption, Eq. III becomes $(de/4)^2 + e^2 = d^2$.  Rearranging yields $e^2 = d^2 (1 -e^2/4)$.  This implies that $|e| < 2$, as otherwise the right-hand side would be negative (or zero) while the left-hand side is positive.  Thus, we must have $e = \pm 1$, which implies that $1 = d^2 * (3/4)$, and thus $d$ cannot be an integer.

All of this taken together then implies that

> the bolded assumption above is false:  $e = 0$, which implies that $d = -4$ and $c$ is odd.

From here, it's a straight run to the finish:

> The remaining equations are equivalent to $8 = -4c + f$, $f = 2g$, $-4c = \bigstar + g$, and $4\bigstar + c = 1 + f$.  This is a linear system of four equations and four unknowns, and it has a unique solution.  Solving this system via a large amount of tedious algebra yields $c = 5$, $f = 28$, $g = 14$, and $\bigstar = 6$.

Comment: I've probably missed a loophole somewhere in this proof.  Any hints as to where it is would be appreciated.

Comment: Fermat's last theorem is only valid for _natural_ numbers $b$, $d$, $e$. But you are allowed to use any _integer_ numbers.

Comment: ... And there's the loophole.  I had a mental argument against negative values of $d$ and $e$ (now articulated), but I had missed the case where $e = 0$.  Thanks, @A.P.

Answer (score 2):

1. $I$ has two possible solutions:

   > $a=0$ or $a=1$. These are the only solutions in $\mathbb{C}$ (let alone $\mathbb{Z}$) to the equation $a^2-a=0$.
2. Given the above, we can tell from $II$ that:

   > $a=1$ and $b=4$, since the alternative would be $a=b=0$ and we know $a\neq b$.
3. Considering $III$ in light of Fermat's last theorem, we know that

   > **if we assume $d,e\geq0$,** then $c\not>2$ and $c\not<-2$. Clearly $c$ cannot be $0$, since then the equation would be $1+1=1$ and invalid. Nor can it be $1$, since then $a=c$, contradiction. Nor can it be $-1$, since then equation $IV$ would yield $b=f$, contradiction. Nor can it be $-2$, since then $$4^{-2}+d^{-2}=e^{-2}\Rightarrow d^2+16=\Big(\frac{4d}{e}\Big)^2\Rightarrow d=3,\frac{4d}{e}=5.$$ So we must have $c=2,d=3,e=5$. Then $IV$ gives $f=-5$ and $V$ gives $-5=7g$, contradiction.

   Thus we must have

   > at least one of $d$ and $e$ being non-positive. Clearly $d=0$ is impossible, since it would give $e=b$. Negative $d$ and positive $e$ would rearrange to an equation of the same FLT form with all bases positive, so that's out too. ($c=2,d=5,e=3$ is just as much of a contradiction from the next two equations as $c=2,d=3,e=5$ was.) Ditto for negative $d$ and negative $e$, while positive $d$ and negative $e$ is just impossible. So we must have  $e=0$.

   I went with this to get

   > $d=-4$ and $c$ odd.
4. Now $IV,V,VI,VII$ become:

   - > $f=8+4c$.
   - > $f=2g$, so $g=4+2c$.
   - > $4c=\bigstar+g$, so $\bigstar=2c-4$.
   - > $4\bigstar+c=1+f$, so $9c-16=9+4c$, giving $c=5$.

**So the solution is:**

> $a=1,b=4,c=5,d=-4,e=0,f=28,g=14$

with the variable $\bigstar$ being

> $6$.

Comment: You may now grant yourself the title of __Mercury__ and brag about it. Work ongoing to find loopholes in the proofs