# Find the value of $\bigstar$: Puzzle 11 - No such thing as equality

Tags: mathematics, number-theory

This puzzle replaces **all** numbers with other symbols.

Your job, as the title suggests, is to find what value fits in the place of $\bigstar$. To get the basic idea, I recommend you solve [Puzzle 1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/59396/find-the-value-of-bigstar-puzzle-1) first.

All symbols follow these rules:

1. Each numerical symbol represents integers and **only integers**. This means fractions and irrational numbers like $\sqrt2$ are not allowed. However, negative numbers and zero are allowed.
2. Each symbol represents a **unique** number. This means that for any two symbols $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in the puzzle, $\alpha\neq\beta$.
3. The following <strike>equations</strike> inequalities are satisfied (this is the heart of the puzzle):
   $$
   \text{I. }a^{a}-a<a\times a
   \\
   \space
   \\
   \text{II. }b\times b-a^{a}\times b<a
   \\
   \space
   \\
   \text{III. }b^{c}<a\times a\times c
   \\
   \space
   \\
   \text{IV. }d\times d-c\times d+c\times c<c\times d+a
   \\
   \space
   \\
   \text{V. }a\times e^a\times c>d^{e}
   \\
   \space
   \\
   \text{VI. }e\times c<a\times b-a\times d
   \\
   \space
   \\
   \text{VII. }e^{a}<\bigstar<a\times b^{a}
   $$

### What is a Solution?

A solution is a value for $\bigstar$, such that, for the set of symbols in the puzzle $S_1$ there is a subtitution $f:S_1\to\Bbb Z$ that satisfies all given equations.

Can you prove that there is **only one** possible value for $\bigstar$, and find that value?

## Good luck!

*Side Note*: to get $\bigstar$ use `$\bigstar$`, and to get $\text^$ use `$\text^$`

---

Previous puzzles:

Introduction:
[#1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/59396) [#2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/59405) [#3](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/59413) [#4](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/59421) [#5](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/59451) [#6](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/59455) [#7](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/59487)

Inequalities:
[#8](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/59606) [#9](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/61050) [#10](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/92477)

[Next puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/121866)

Comment: Should we assume that only letters and ★ are integers, and all other symbols have their usual meanings?

Comment: in this one, yes. I usually say that the symbols are unknown in the puzzle description, and I use different symbols to avoid confusion

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Solving (1) shows that $a$ is either a negative integer (if $a\le-2$, $a^a$ is some number with magnitude less than $1$ and $a^2+a$ is positive; the inequality also holds when $a=-1$) or $1$ or $2$. $0$ is excluded because $0^0=1$.

> If $a$ is a negative integer, the magnitude argument on $a^a$ shows that the left-hand side of (2), a quadratic in $b$, is always nonnegative when $b$ is an integer, which leads to a contradiction. Simple casework then shows that $(a,b)$ can only take one of five possibilities:
>  $$\{(1,0),(2,0),(2,1),(2,3),(2,4)\}$$

> We jump to (4), which can be rearranged to $(c-d)^2<a$. If $a=1$, since everything is an integer $(c-d)^2$ must be $0$, so $c=d$ which violates the "unequal values" constraint. Thus $a$ is forced to be $2$ and $|c-d|=1$ (which way we don't know yet) and $b\in\{0,1,3,4\}$.

> Now (3), which is $b^c<4c$, solves as follows: $b=4$ leads to no solution, $b=3$ forces $c=1$, $b=0$ or $b=1$ merely constrains $c\ge1$.

> (5) and (6) are now $2ce^2>d^e$ and $ec<2(b-d)$ respectively. If $c\ge3$ then $d\ge3$ as well (it can't assume the value of $a$), but then $b$ is $0$ or $1$ so the right-hand side of (6) is at most $2(1-3)=-4$. Then $e$ must be negative. We now look at (7), which is $e^2<\bigstar<0$ if $b=0$ – impossible – so $b=1$ and $e^2<\bigstar<2$, forcing $e=0$ and $\bigstar=1$ which violates the unequal values constraint.

> Hence $c\ge3$ leads to a contradiction in any case, so $c=1$ and $d=0$, forcing $b=3$. A $0^e$ term now appears in (5), so $e$ is nonnegative; (6) becomes $e<6$, so $e=4$ or $e=5$. The latter choice gives $25<\bigstar<18$ which is impossible; the former gives $16<\bigstar<18$ and we finally have $\bigstar=17$.

Answer (score 3):

> EQ (1) gives $a=0,1,2$ but

> EQ (4) has $(c-d)^2$ which eliminates $a=0,1$ & hence $a=2$

> EQ (2) has $b^2-4b+4$ which makes $b=2,1,3,0,4$

> EQ (7) has $2b^2$ which is $0,2,8,18,32$
>  This must be a little larger than a Square, which give $2,8,18$.
>  We get $e=0,1,2,3,4$

> Looks like $e=4$ & $e^2=16$
>  which makes $b=3$ & $2b^2=18$
>  leaving $\bigstar=17$

[[ I will complete the analysis , figuring out the other letters , if my thinking is correct ]]

Comment: I've beaten you to it.

Comment: Oh Ok ! No Problem ! Observation : Assuming that both our Answers are correct , I was earlier by 7 minutes , in giving the final answer & then pausing while waiting for feedback from OP , @ParclyTaxel

Comment: Hi, the answer is correct, now all that's left is to show it is the only possible answer. In particular, in eq.1 did you find all the possible values for $a$?

Comment: I had Heuristically eliminated Negative values for $a$ because , in that Case , EQ (7) will have Positive less than Negative (IMPOSSIBLE) & I had also used EQ (4) to conclude that $C$ & $D$ Differ by 2 , but that was not changing the outcome that $\bigstar = 17$ , hence I did not list it in the Answer. Overall : good effort in solving this Puzzle , @ParclyTaxel .....

Comment: .... & good effort in making this Puzzle , @NODO55 .... [[ +1 ]] to both of you !