# Find the value of $\bigstar$: Puzzle 12 - Not enough variables

Tags: mathematics, number-theory

This puzzle replaces **all** numbers (and operations) with other symbols.

Your job, as the title suggests, is to find what value fits in the place of $\bigstar$. To get the basic idea, I recommend you solve [Puzzle 1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/59396) and [Puzzle 5](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/59451) first.

All symbols follow these rules:

1. - Each numerical symbol represents integers and **only integers**. This means fractions and irrational numbers like $\sqrt2$ are not allowed. However, negative numbers and zero are allowed.
   - Any symbol that is NOT numerical must be one of the following operations: $\{+,-,\times,\text{^}\}$. *Notice how all operation are binary operations. This means that all operation symbols must have a number on their left and on their right. Use that fact to your advantage!*
2. Each symbol represents a **unique** number/operation. This means that for any two symbols $\alpha$ and $\beta$ which are in the same puzzle, $\alpha\neq\beta$.
3. The following equations/inequalities are satisfied (this is the heart of the puzzle):
   $$
   \begin{array}{lc}
   \text{I. }&\qquad a\ @\ a<a\ \#\ a\ \#\ a
   \\\space\\
   \text{II. }&\qquad b\ $\ c=c\ $\ b\ @\ b
   \\\space\\
   \text{III. }&\qquad d\ @\ d\ \#\ a<c\ $\ b
   \\\space\\
   \text{IV. }&\qquad e\ \%\ a\ \%\ e=e\ \%e\ \%\ c\ @\ a\ @\ b
   \\\space\\
   \text{V. }&\qquad c\ \%\ f=a\ \%\ f\ \#\ b\ \%\ f
   \\\space\\
   \text{VI. }&\qquad g\ $\ g\ @\ d\ \#\ e<f\ \%\ f
   \\\space\\
   \text{VII. }&\qquad c\ $\ c\ $\ c\ $\ c\ $\ c\ \%\ d\ $\ d\ $\ d<h\ \#\ b\ \#\ h
   \\\space\\
   \text{VIII. }&\qquad a\ \#\ i=a\ $\ i\ $\ i\ \#\ a
   \\\space\\
   \text{IX. }&\qquad e\ \#\ h\ $\ e\ \#\ h<\bigstar<e\ $\ c\ $\ c\ @\ a
   \end{array}
   $$

### What is a Solution?

A solution is a value for $\bigstar$, such that, for the set of numerical symbols in the puzzle $S_1$ and the set of operator symbols in the puzzle $S_2$ there is a subtitution $f:S_1\to\Bbb Z$ and $g:S_2\to\{+,-,\times,\text{^}\}$ that satisfies all given equations.

Can you prove that there is **only one** possible value for $\bigstar$, and find that value?

*Some nice symbols for your solution:*

- $\bigstar:\;$ `$\bigstar$`
- $\text^:\;$ `$\text^$`
- $\#:\;$ `$\#$`
- $\%:\;$ `$\%$`
- $\mapsto:\;$ `$\mapsto$`

## Good luck!

---

Previous puzzles:

Introduction:
[#1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/59396) [#2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/59405) [#3](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/59413) [#4](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/59421) [#5](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/59451) [#6](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/59455) [#7](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/59487)

Inequalities:
[#8](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/59606) [#9](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/61050) [#10](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/92477) [#11](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/118345)

Comment: In the making of this puzzle I also created a function (in Mathematica) that converts the symbols into all the possible configurations. Should I share it?

Comment: Should we assume that the usual rules of operator precedence apply? (So that, e.g.,, a @ b & c means (a @ b) & c if @ is * and & is +, but it means a @ (b & c) if @ is + and & is *.)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Yes, the usual rules apply

Comment: Should we assume < and = have their usual meaning?

Comment: @msh210 Yes. If I were to replace them as well, I would use "unoccupied" symbols to avoid confusion

Comment: Just to clarify, is a^b^c = (a^b)^c or a^(b^c)? Also, is a-b+c = (a-b)+c or a-(b+c)?

Comment: Also, is a*b^c = (a*b)^c or a*(b^c)? Thanks

Comment: @hexomino since the usual order of operations applies, $a\text^b\text^c=a\text^(b\text^c)$, $a-b+c=(a-b)+c$, $a*b\text^c = a*(b\text^c)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the solution is as follows

> $\# \mapsto \text^$
>  $@ \mapsto +$
>  $\\\$ \mapsto \times$
>  $ \% \mapsto -$
>  $a = -1$
>  $b = 0$
>  $c = -2$
>  $d = -3$
>  $e=3$.
>  $f$ can be anything.
>  $|g| < 6$
>  $h=1$
>  $i$ is an odd integer.
>  $\bigstar =10$

What follows is the explanation of how I found this. Apologies for the length, it is essentially a lot of case-bashing. The solution is found at the very end. Apologies also for any mistakes, there are probably a few in here.

Case 1

> $\# \mapsto -$
>  This would mean that the right hand side of the first inequality is $-a$.
>  If $@ \mapsto \times$ then the left hand side is non-negative (a square) and so $a$ must be strictly negative. But since $a^2 < -a$, it can only be that $-1 < a< 0$ and this is not allowed.
>  If $@ \mapsto +$ then the left hand side is $2a$ and it must be that $a$ is strictly negative, we call this case 1.(i).
>  If $@ \mapsto \text^$ then the left hand side is $a^a$ and again $a$ must be negative, we call this case 1.(ii).

Case 1.(i)

> If $ \\\$ \mapsto \times$ then, by equation **II**, $b \times c = c \times b + b$ and $b=0$.
>  This would mean $\% \mapsto \text^$ and equation **V** gives $c^f = a^f - b^f$ but since $b=0$ and $f \neq 0$ it forces $c=-a$ and $f$ must be even (thanks OP).
>  Equation **VIII** becomes $a-i = ai^2 - a$ or $a = \frac{i}{2-i^2}$ The right hand side here is an integer only when $i=-2,-1,0,1$ and $2$ and is different to $a$ only when $i=-2$ (where $a=1$) or $i=2$ (where $a=-1$) and since we've established that $a$ is negative, it must be that $a=-1$ and $i=2$ and thus $c=1$.
>  Looking at equation **IV**, the right hand side is $e^e - 1$ and the left hand side is either $e$, if $e$ is even or $1/e$, if $e$ is odd. The only integer solution here is $e=0$ but we already have $b=0$ so there is no overall solution in this case. 
>  Alternatively, if $ \\\$ \mapsto \text^$ then equation **II** gives $b^c = c^b + b$.
>  A little bit of work can show us that this equation admits just two integer solutions, namely $(b,c) = (0,0)$ (disallowed for being equal) or $(b,c) = (1,0)$. This also means $\% \mapsto \times$ and equation **V** gives $0 = af - f$ and since $a<0$, it must be that $f=0=c$ which is not allowed so there are no possible solutions in case 1.(i).

Case 1.(ii)

> If $ \\\$ \mapsto \times$ then equation **II** tells us that $bc = cb^b$ which means that either $c=0$ or $b=-1$ or $1$.
>  This would also mean that $\% \mapsto +$ and equation **IV** gives $e+a+e = e+e+c^{a^b}$ or $a = c^{a^b}$. This rules out $c=0$ as $a$ would be $0$. If $b=1$ or $-1$ then $c = a^{1/a}$ or $a^a$ but $a=-1$ gives $c=-1$ and other negative values of $a$ make $c$ non integral.
>  Alternatively, if $ \\\$ \mapsto +$ the equation **II** becomes $b+c = c+b^b$ which means $b=1$ or $-1$. In this case, $ \% \mapsto \times$ and  equation **IV** tells us that $c = a^{1/a}$ or $a^a$ (which runs into the same problems as previous) or that $e=0$.
>  If $e=0$, it means that $f \neq 0$ and we can factor it out of equation **V** to get $c = a-b$. Plugging this into equation **III**, gives us $d^d = 2a$ but this isn't possible since $a$ is a negative integer and the minimum possible for $d^d$ is $-1$. Hence, there are no possible solutions in case 1.(ii)

Case 2

> $\# \mapsto +$
>  This puts the right hand side of equation **I** as $3a$.
>  If $@ \mapsto -$ then the left hand side of **I** is 0 so we have $a>0$. We call this case 2.(i).
>  If $@ \mapsto \times$ then we have $a^2 < 3a$ so that $a = 1$ or $2$. We call this case 2.(ii). 
>  If $@ \mapsto \text^$ then we have $a^a < 3a$ so that $a=1$ or $2$. We call this case 2.(iii)

Case 2.(i)

> If $ \\\$ \mapsto \times$ then equation **II** gives $b=0$. But then equation **III** gives $d^d + a < 0$ which is not possible with $a > 0$.
>  Alternatively, if $ \\\$ \mapsto \text^$, equation **II** becomes $b^c = c^b - b$ which has integer solutions $(b,c) = (0,0)$  (forbidden) and $(b,c) = (1,2)$. Looking at equation **III**, we have $a < c^b$ which is $2$ which puts $a=1=b$. Hence there are no solutions in Case 2.(i).

Case 2.(ii)

> If $\\\$ \mapsto -$ then equation **VIII** gives $3i = a$ which makes $i$ non-integral as $a=1$ or $2$.
>  Alternatively, if $\\\$ \mapsto \text^$ then equation **VIII** gives $i = a^{i^i}$ which has no real solutions for $i$ when $a=2$ and gives $i=1$ when $a=1$. Hence, there are no solutions in case 2.(ii)

Case 2.(iii)

> Again $\\\$ \mapsto -$ gives us the same issue with $a$ as in 2.(ii).
>  Alternatively, if $\\\$ \mapsto \times$, equation **VIII** gives $i=ai^2$ which only has integer solutions $i=1=a$ (disallowed) or $i=0$. However, equation **II** gives $b=0$ so this does not work. Hence, there are no solutions in case 2.(iii)

Case 3

> $\# \mapsto \times$
>  If $@ \mapsto +$ then it must be that $a>1$, we call this case 3.(i)
>  If $@ \mapsto -$ then we must have $a>0$, we call this case 3.(ii)
>  If $@ \mapsto \text^$ then the only possibility is $a=2$, we call this case 3.(iii)

Case 3.(i)

> If $\\\$ \mapsto -$ then equation **VIII** becomes $2ai = a-i$ or $i = \frac{a}{2a+1}$ which is non-integral for $a>1$.
>  Alternatively, if $\\\$ \mapsto \text^$ then equation **VIII** becomes $ i = a^{i^i}$ which has no solutions for $a>1$. Hence there are no solutions in case 3.(i).

Case 3.(ii)

> If $ \\\$ \mapsto +$ then equation **II** gives $b=0$. Equation **V** gives $a^f = c^f$ and since $f \neq 0$ and $a \neq c$ it forces $f$ to be even and $a=-c$. However, equation **VIII** gives directly $a=-i$, forcing $c=i$ which is not allowed.
>  Alternatively, if $ \\\$ \mapsto \text^$ then **VIII** gives $i = a^{i^i}$ which, as before, does not lead to a valid solution. Hence there are no solutions in case 3.(ii)

Case 3.(iii)

> If $ \\\$ \mapsto +$ then equation **II** gives $b = b^b$ meaning that $b=1$ or $-1$.
>  Equation **IV** then gives us $a = c^{a^b}$ which makes $c$ irrational if $b=1$, but if $b=-1$ then $c=4$.
>  However, equation **V** then tells us that $4-f = (2-f)(-1-f)$ or $f^2 = 6$ which makes $f$ irrational and therefore, no solution in this case.
>  Alternatively, if $ \\\$ \mapsto -$, equation **VIII** gives $4i = 2-i$ or $i=2/5$ which is not an integer. Hence, there is no solution in case 3.(iii)

Case 4

> $\# \mapsto \text^$
>  $a<-1$ seems to sometimes create imaginary values on the right hand side of **I** when $a$ is even but there seem to be valid real numbers in play when $a$ is odd so we'll restrict to these values.
>  If $@ \mapsto -$ then the left hand side of **I** is 0 and we just require $a>0$. We call this case 4.(i)
>  If $@ \mapsto \times$ then the inequality is satisfied only when $a>1$. We call this case 4.(ii)
>  If $@ \mapsto +$ it appears that $a$ can take any negative odd value and also any value $a>1$. We call this case 4.(iii)

Case 4.(i)

> If $\\\$ \mapsto +$ then equation **VIII** gives $a^i = a + i + i^a$. Any values of $i < -1$ will create a non-integer quantity on the left which cannot be rectified by the integer value of the right hand side. After that, we just need to check through a small number of values for $a$ and $i$ before realising that the largeness of $a^i - i^a$ cannot be compensated by $a+i$. In this case the solutions are $(a,i) = (1,0)$ or $(2,5)$.
>  Equation **II** implies $b=0$ so it must be that $a=2$ and $i=5$.
>  Equation **V** then gives $cf = 2f$ which means that $c=2=a$ or $f=0=b$ so this case doesn't work.
>  Alternatively, if $\\\$ \mapsto \times$ the equation **II** gives $b=0$ and equation **IV** gives $c=2a$.
>  Then equation **V** gives $c=a+1$ so that $a=1$ and $c=2$.
>  Inequality **III** then gives $0 < 0$ which is not allowed so there is no solution in case 4.(i)

Case 4.(ii)

> If $ \\\$ \mapsto +$ then again equation **VIII** implies $(a,i) = (2,5)$ (as $(1,0)$ has already been disallowed).
>  Equation **II** implies $b=b^2$ so that $b=0$ or $b=1$.
>  However, equation **IV** then gives us $bc = 1$ which means $b=c=1$.
>  Alternatively, if $ \\\$ \mapsto -$ then equation **VIII** gives $a^i + i^a = a-i$. If $a$ is less than $-1$ then the right hand side of this equation is an integer where the left cannot be, similarly when $i<-1$. If both numbers are greater than $1$, then the left hand side is clearly bigger. The only solution we can get here is thus $a=1, i=0$ but this has already been disallowed. Hence there are no solutions in case 4.(ii)

Case 4.(iii)

> If $ \\\$ \mapsto -$ then equation **VIII** gives $a^i + i^a = a-i$. As before, the only solution we can get here is $a=1, i=0$ but this value for $a$ is disallowed by **I**.
>  Alternatively, suppose $\\\$ \mapsto \times$.
>  Then equation **II** gives $b=0$. Equation **V** then gives us $c = a-1$ and equation **IV** gives $c=2a$. Thus $a=-1$ and $c=-2$.
>  Equation **VIII** then gives $(-1)^i = -1$ which tells us $i$ is odd.
>  Inequality **III** tells us that $d + d^{-1} < 0$ and so $d$ is negative and necessarily less than $-2$ so as not to cross paths with $a$ and $c$.
>  In inequality **VII**, if $h < -1$, then the right hand side is $-\infty$ (something that I missed before) so $h > 0$. Inequality **VII** then tells us that $c^5 - d^3 < 1$ which means that $d^3 > -33$ and so $d=-3$.
>  Inequality **VI** gives $g^2 + d^e < 0$ which means that $e$ is necessarily odd and $>1$ as $e=1$ forces $|g| < 2$ and all values in this range are already taken.
>  Finally inequality **IX** gives $e^{2h} < \bigstar < ec^2 + a = 4e-1$.
>  Since $h > 0$ the only value of $e$ which can make the left smaller than the right is $e=3$ and then we must have $h=1$. Then $e^{2h} = 9$, $4e-1 = 11$ and $\bigstar=10$ is the singular value which works.

Comment: You missed something that restricts exactly what you need. It is a bit sneaky, but consider consulting the original equations

Comment: Also, in case 1.i.a, have you considered $f\in \mathbb{Z}_{even}$?

Comment: I also found minor issues in cases 1.i.b, 2.i.b, 4.iii (I don't know any a<-1 such that $a^{a^a}\in \mathbb{R}$) but I think these are trivial enough

Comment: @NODO55 yes, you're right, I have made some mistakes, will fix these up. Regarding $a^{a^a}$, if $a=-3$, for example then this is $(-3)^{-1/27}$ and I think there is a real root here (essentially the negative of the 27th root of 1/3). This works for all negative odd numbers but not evens.

Comment: If we disregard the magnitude component and search for $(-1)^{-1/27}$ using De Moivre's formula we see that $(-1)^{-1/27}\in\{e^{i\theta}\|\theta=\frac\pi{27}(2n-1),n\in\{1..27\}\}$, since $\frac{2n-1}{27}$ never resolves to a half-whole integer, no solution can resolve to an integer.

Comment: @NODO55 What about $n=14$? That's a whole integer, even better. Gives $-1$ as one of the roots.

Comment: Nevermind, seems I disproved my own claim. Still, there are multiple solutions to the "negative root of a negative number". I don't exactly know what the convention is in this case

Comment: @NODO55 That's the trouble with exponents and logs, you quickly get into one-to-many mappings. My thinking here was that if a real root exists, use that.

Comment: @NODO55 I've just seen the thing I've missed, thanks for the nudge.